# How can I backup my laptop to my ubuntu PC over the ethernet using clonezilla?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, partitioning, backup, clonezilla

After searching the web for hours, I couldn't find a noob-guide for getting the job done. I have read bits of disconnected information here and there about nfs servers, dhcp, samba and so on. I've even tried some methods without yielding any results.

I have a laptop with a single NTFS partition. I also have an ubuntu desktop, an ethernet cable and a bootable clonezilla live cd. What I'm intending to do is to backup the NTFS partition to my ubuntu desktop (as an image). I don't know how to setup a static IP on my computer and use it via clonezilla to access the network-share. I have, however, used clonezilla before to backup an ubuntu partition (ext4) to another. Any guides, outlines or tutorials will be of help.

**update**
I have tried @bjanssen's answer right away and failed!

```
ip addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether bc:ae:c5:b9:94:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::beae:c5ff:feb9:9443/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I couldn't locate my IP address among these. I have tried dhcp discovery in clonezilla which keeps on checking the network (more like pinging) and stays that way.

Comment: I presume this is the output of your Ubuntu machine. Apparently there are more preparations required before you can think about making an image over the network. First order of the day: get your network up and running.

Answer (score 1):

That should be straight forward. Check if you Ubuntu machine offers SSH access (by default it does) and if you have a dhcp server in your network (you probably have.)

Boot your Ubuntu laptop and make a note of the used IP, i. e. type `ip addr` in a terminal or use the funky NetworkManager applet. Make sure that you have your username and password ready.

Boot your Windows laptop from the live cd and let Clonezilla fetch an IP address from your dhcp server. In the step to select an image directory, select "server_ssh Use SSH Server" (see here for a walkthrough with pictures: http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-usage/general-live-use.php) Now Clonezilla will walk you through the SSH connection. Once the connection is established, continue as usual.

Comment: I've updated the question after trying your solution.